# Fix SassError, relating to cannot find stylesheet when upgrading to webpacker version 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

After upgrading from webpacker version 4 to version 5.3.4, I am seeing the following error.

```
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "stylesheet/actiontext.scss"
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade to version 5 of `webpacker` made some breaking changes, including how to specify the loading of scss and scss files in ruby on rails apps. Previously in `application.js` I had

```
#app/javascripts/packs/application.js
...
import 'application.scss'
```

and my `application.scss` file contained

```
#app/javascripts/application.scss
@import '/stylesheets/datatables.scss';
@import '/stylesheets/actiontext.scss'
```

which pointed to my `app/javascript/stylesheets` folder which contained the two files `datatables.scss, actiontext.scss`

Version 5 of webpacker has simplified this, so you do not need to specify the configuration. So to fix the problem

1. move your scss (or css) files from the `app/javascript/stylesheets` folder to the `app/javascripts/packs` folder
2. remove the @import directive from `app/javascripts/packs/application.js`
3. when all is working, delete the `app/javascript/stylesheets` folder and the `app/javascripts/application.scss` file.
   This [post](https://prathamesh.tech/2020/03/25/webpacker-5-0-released/) has more details.